# How to filter with enum or string and get a same result?

Tags: python, django, enums

I have a hard time using Enums in Django.

This is my Request model:

```
class RequestStatuses(Enum):
    new = 'new'
    sent = 'sent'
    done = 'done'


class Request(BaseModel):


    request_number =    models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    type =              models.CharField(max_length=31, blank=True, null=True)

    status =            models.CharField(
        max_length=31,
        choices=[(a.name, a.value) for a in RequestStatuses],
        default=RequestStatuses.new
    )

    sensor =            models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    device =            models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    user =              models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payload =           models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

There is a difference when I create the record with string, or the enum type, which is really annoying...

This works just fine:

```
    device = Device.objects.create(serial_number=1)
    request = Request(
        device=self.device,
        status=RequestStatuses.sent
    )
    request.save()
    try:
        request = device.request_set.filter(
            status=RequestStatuses.sent
        )[0]
    except IndexError:
        print(device.request_set.all()[0].status)
        pass
```

But this throws an exception

```
    device = Device.objects.create(serial_number=1)
    request = Request(
        device=device,
        status='sent'
    )
    request.save()
    try:
        request = device.request_set.filter(
            status=RequestStatuses.sent
        )[0]
    except IndexError:
        print(device.request_set.all()[0].status)
        pass
```

When I try to filter with `status=RequestStatuses.sent.value` or just with `sent` string the first example throws an exception and second works.

What is the point of enums, when you can't filter them by string or vice versa? How can I make it work with api - which will pass string to a filter? Or is it just some cache issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Request model you you need to modify definition of "status"

```
status = models.CharField(
        max_length=31,
        choices= RequestStatuses.choices(),
        default=RequestStatuses.new.value
    )
```

Then you may filter following way.

```
request = Request.objects.filter(status=RequestStatuses.new.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know the reason why and whether it is allright to do this, but adding `__repr__` and `__str__` functions to the enum resolved the issue.

```
class RequestStatuses(Enum):
    new = 'new'
    sent = 'sent'
    done = 'done'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```